# Why is # unrecognized in a Rails SQL statement?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models, Message and User. Message has two User objects, user_1 and user_2.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_1, :user_2

  belongs_to :user_1, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :user_2, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password

  has_many :message, dependent: :destroy, :finder_sql => 'SELECT * FROM messages where (user_1_id = #{id} or user_2_id = #{id})'
end
```

When I try and delete the User object, I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#destroy
>
> SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "#": SELECT * FROM messages
>   where (user_1_id = #{id} or user_2_id = #{id})

The error message seems plain enough, but I thought # was the correct syntax. I'm using Rails 3.2.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby everything inside single quotes except `\\` and `\'` is treated literally.

You will have to use double quotes for your SQL statement.